# CSS: How to align an image right without its cutting into the bottom?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment, css-float

I'm having difficulty while trying to align my layout properly. Here I have a blog post template, and I want to make the text flow around an image aligned to the right properly.

Here's how my code goes (I've cut a lot of code unnecessary for this example and I'll use inline styles for brevity):

HTML (this code uses some Bootstrap classes)

```
 <div>
   <img src="ubuntu.png" style="float: right;">
   <p>Image caption</p>
 </div>
 <p>Some lovely blog post text.</p>
 <hr/>
```

But if the number of lines of the `<p>` text doesn't make the overall text higher than the embedded image, the image will break the layout by "conflicting" with the horizontal line (no normal carrying over happens, like when the `float: right` part is removed).

So it looks like the image below. There, the image cuts into the bottom part of the blog. But if the `float` attribute is removed, it doesn't cut into it, but doesn't get aligned right.

[image]

I'm not a CSS pro. What is a proper way to do the alignment in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the float.

```
.clearfix:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

add that class to a containing div for the `<img>`

Example:

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
before
<div class="square"></div>
after
<hr> before
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="square" style="float:right"></div>
</div>

after
<hr> before
<div class="square" style="float:right"></div>
after
<hr>
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. I've never seen such constructs in CSS before.